# Webpage in IIS is slow

Tags: iis-8.5

I have a PHP page(website hosted in IIS 8.5) which is loading very slow, it takes more than 15 seconds to load.

It connects to a remote SQL server and display the result of the query, i tried executing the query in SQL Management studio and the results are returned within 1 second.

The same page(copied the file) from a different webserver is loading very fast(<1 sec).

I enabled Request Tracing in IIS for the website and when i looked at the results, the time taken for the response is 11000 msec, but the total ms as per the tracing steps is <100 msec.

I dont know where the webpage or IIS is blocked for many seconds before sending the result to client.

Comment: What do you mean by "but the total ms as per the tracing steps is <100 msec"? Show the tracing result (like screen shots).

Comment: I have modified my Failed Request Tracing rule and found that GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER  is taking almost all the time. Please let me know why this takes more time

Comment: @BanusundarArumugam Did you ever find any more about what was happening here? I'm seeing a long time (>3 seconds) for a GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER in the trace as well.